# Are column alias'/ calculated columns not returned in SQL Server 2008 sprocs?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I just added a couple of calculated columns to a stored procedure that returns a result set. I call it from C#/ .NET. The new columns (to on the end) are both returning a value of 0. Here's the first row of what I get back, and the sproc below it:

```
Daily Pricing and Volume        5/4/2012    5229    5249    5256    0   0


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spProcedureStatsCollectionCountComparisons]

AS

DECLARE @MaxDataDownloadDate date

SET @MaxDataDownloadDate = dbo.MostRecentTradeDateForDataDownload()

SELECT ProcedureName, TradeDate, LatestCount, PriorCount, AvgAllCounts, 
    ((LatestCount-PriorCount)/PriorCount) AS PctChgLatestVsPrior, 
    ((LatestCount-AvgAllCounts)/AvgAllCounts) AS PctChgLatestVsAvg
FROM vwProcedureStatsCollectionCountComparisons
WHERE TradeDate = @MaxDataDownloadDate
```

My question is, can I not use column alias' in a result set from a stored procedure, or is there some other issue at work that I'm missing? Thanks in advance..

As requested, the relevant C# code:

```
SqlDataReader collectionCounts = dal.ProcedureStatsCollectionCountComparisons();
int rowCounter = 4;
while (collectionCounts.Read())
{

    wkhst.Cells[rowCounter, 1] = collectionCounts["ProcedureName"];
    wkhst.Cells[rowCounter, 2] = collectionCounts["TradeDate"];
    wkhst.Cells[rowCounter, 3] = collectionCounts["LatestCount"];
    wkhst.Cells[rowCounter, 4] = collectionCounts["PriorCount"];
    wkhst.Cells[rowCounter, 5] = collectionCounts["AvgAllCounts"];
    wkhst.Cells[rowCounter, 6] = collectionCounts["PctChgLatestVsPrior"];
    wkhst.Cells[rowCounter, 7] = collectionCounts["PctChgLatestVsAvg"];

    rowCounter++;
}

excelApp.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Show us your C# code. The should be no problems with using alias columns

Comment: It must be some other issue, I have SPs who use column aliases like in your example in a 2008 server, and they work fine. What datatype are your *count variables? Could they be unsigned types, and since the result of (LatestCount-PriorCount) is < 0 it's calculated as 0?

Comment: Treb thanks, I'm not quite sure what you mean by my count varaibles? Maybe the code that shows the result set being added to an excel spreadsheet helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge and based on the data provided, it is working as expected. This is because, you doing something like below.

```
SELECT ((5229 - 5249)/5249)
```

which always returns "0" as the first number is less than the second one.

EDIT:

SELECT (CAST((5229 - 5249) AS FLOAT)/ CAST(5249 AS FLOAT))

Comment: Praveen, thanks, but it wasn't quite what I had expected. ;) Do you know how I'd get back a signed decimal from these computed columns?

Comment: You can cast it to another data type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx. Cast both *count variables, the result should automatically have a matching data type.